# Не отправляются оповещения на емейл об ответе на комментарий

Tags: wordpress, smtp, комментарии

Есть проблема с комментариями на WP. А вернее с отправлением оповещений на email. Когда мне на блоге оставляют комментарий, то мне приходит об этом уведомление, а вот когда я отвечаю пользователю, то ему оповещения на почту указанную при добавлении коммента не приходят. Обращался к хостеру, там сказали что в логах ошибок нет, мол проверяйте скрипт отправки комментариев.

Есть мысли у кого-нить на этот счет?

Comment: А WP в вашем вопросе что это?

Comment: Wordpress обычно так сокращают

Comment: В следующий раз пожалуйста добавляйте метку.

Comment: На маил ру не приходит? Домен сайта свой? метка `smpt` тут к чему? Если отправка через smpt, то нужно писать какой сервер используется .

Comment: Не приходит на майлру и яндекс как минимум, на других не проверял. Домен свой, сервер Apache.

Comment: Читайте про SPF, DKIM, DMARC

Comment: Отправлял тестовое письмо плагином wp mail SMTP - все доходит и на яндекс и на майлру, смею предположить, что SPF, DKIM, DMARC ни при чем. Проблема, видимо, конкретно в скрипте обрабатывающем отправку письма о комменте. Причем как-то выборно у него это происходит, когда мне отправляют, то все отправляется и доходит, когда я отвечаю на коммент, то не доходит пользователю. Вопрос только в том - отправляется ли.